# doing outer for really large data frame hitting memory usage in R

Tags: r, outer-join, sqldf, full-outer-join

So i have three data frame having this information

```
> dim(result)
[1] 652265     10
> dim(rat)
[1] 107190      2
> dim(mouse)
[1] 219016      2
> names(result)
 [1] "ensembl_gene_id"                             "ensembl_transcript_id"                      
 [3] "external_gene_name"                          "mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_gene"             
 [5] "mmusculus_homolog_associated_gene_name"      "rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_gene"           
 [7] "rnorvegicus_homolog_associated_gene_name"    "celegans_homolog_ensembl_gene"              
 [9] "celegans_homolog_associated_gene_name"       "celegans_homolog_ensembl_gene_transcript_id"
> names(rat)
[1] "rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_gene"          "rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_transcript_id"
> names(mouse)
[1] "mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_gene"          "mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_transcript_id"
```

My dataframes are as such

```
head(result)
  ensembl_gene_id ensembl_transcript_id external_gene_name mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_gene
1 ENSG00000198888       ENST00000361390             MT-ND1             ENSMUSG00000064341
2            <NA>                  <NA>               <NA>                           <NA>
3 ENSG00000198804       ENST00000361624             MT-CO1             ENSMUSG00000064351
4 ENSG00000198712       ENST00000361739             MT-CO2             ENSMUSG00000064354
5            <NA>                  <NA>               <NA>                           <NA>
6            <NA>                  <NA>               <NA>                           <NA>
  mmusculus_homolog_associated_gene_name rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_gene
1                                 mt-Nd1               ENSRNOG00000030644
2                                   <NA>                             <NA>
3                                 mt-Co1               ENSRNOG00000034234
4                                 mt-Co2               ENSRNOG00000030371
5                                   <NA>                             <NA>
6                                   <NA>                             <NA>
  rnorvegicus_homolog_associated_gene_name celegans_homolog_ensembl_gene
1                                   Mt-nd1                WBGene00010959
2                                     <NA>                          <NA>
3                                   Mt-co1                WBGene00010964
4                                   Mt-co2                WBGene00010965
5                                     <NA>                          <NA>
6                                     <NA>                          <NA>
  celegans_homolog_associated_gene_name celegans_homolog_ensembl_gene_transcript_id
1                                                                         MTCE.11.1
2                                  <NA>                                        <NA>
3                                 ctc-1                                   MTCE.26.1
4                                 ctc-2                                   MTCE.31.1
5                                  <NA>                                        <NA>
6                                  <NA>                                        <NA>
> head(rat)
  rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_gene rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_transcript_id
1               ENSRNOG00000033395                        ENSRNOT00000044979
2               ENSRNOG00000070901                        ENSRNOT00000119508
3               ENSRNOG00000031391                        ENSRNOT00000045306
4               ENSRNOG00000067904                        ENSRNOT00000099225
5               ENSRNOG00000067904                        ENSRNOT00000099225
6               ENSRNOG00000067904                        ENSRNOT00000099225
> head(mouse)
  mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_gene mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_transcript_id
1             ENSMUSG00000064341                      ENSMUST00000082392
2             ENSMUSG00000064345                      ENSMUST00000082396
3             ENSMUSG00000064351                      ENSMUST00000082402
4             ENSMUSG00000064354                      ENSMUST00000082405
5             ENSMUSG00000064356                      ENSMUST00000082407
6             ENSMUSG00000064357                      ENSMUST00000082408
```

I tried sqldf based solution since dplyr was stuck when i tried

```
joined_data <- sqldf("
    SELECT *
    FROM result
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rat ON result.rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_gene = rat.rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_gene
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mouse ON result.mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_gene = mouse.mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_gene
")
```

The issue is it just hit the upper limit of the system i have with me

Now what is the optimized way to do the same if any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

[image: R memory usage]

**UPDATE_data**

```
dput(head(result))
structure(list(ensembl_gene_id = c("ENSG00000198888", NA, "ENSG00000198804", 
"ENSG00000198712", NA, NA), ensembl_transcript_id = c("ENST00000361390", 
NA, "ENST00000361624", "ENST00000361739", NA, NA), external_gene_name = c("MT-ND1", 
NA, "MT-CO1", "MT-CO2", NA, NA), mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_gene = c("ENSMUSG00000064341", 
NA, "ENSMUSG00000064351", "ENSMUSG00000064354", NA, NA), mmusculus_homolog_associated_gene_name = c("mt-Nd1", 
NA, "mt-Co1", "mt-Co2", NA, NA), rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_gene = c("ENSRNOG00000030644", 
NA, "ENSRNOG00000034234", "ENSRNOG00000030371", NA, NA), rnorvegicus_homolog_associated_gene_name = c("Mt-nd1", 
NA, "Mt-co1", "Mt-co2", NA, NA), celegans_homolog_ensembl_gene = c("WBGene00010959", 
NA, "WBGene00010964", "WBGene00010965", NA, NA), celegans_homolog_associated_gene_name = c("", 
NA, "ctc-1", "ctc-2", NA, NA), celegans_homolog_ensembl_gene_transcript_id = c("MTCE.11.1", 
NA, "MTCE.26.1", "MTCE.31.1", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
 dput(head(rat))
structure(list(rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_gene = c("ENSRNOG00000033395", 
"ENSRNOG00000070901", "ENSRNOG00000031391", "ENSRNOG00000067904", 
"ENSRNOG00000067904", "ENSRNOG00000067904"), rnorvegicus_homolog_ensembl_transcript_id = c("ENSRNOT00000044979", 
"ENSRNOT00000119508", "ENSRNOT00000045306", "ENSRNOT00000099225", 
"ENSRNOT00000099225", "ENSRNOT00000099225")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
 dput(head(mouse))
structure(list(mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_gene = c("ENSMUSG00000064341", 
"ENSMUSG00000064345", "ENSMUSG00000064351", "ENSMUSG00000064354", 
"ENSMUSG00000064356", "ENSMUSG00000064357"), mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_transcript_id = c("ENSMUST00000082392", 
"ENSMUST00000082396", "ENSMUST00000082402", "ENSMUST00000082405", 
"ENSMUST00000082407", "ENSMUST00000082408")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You have sample data, but it's a bit onerous to import data from the console output when the columns span multiple sets of rows. Can you share the sample data as well using `dput(head(x))`? Also, it looks as if none of the sample data here will actually join, none of the levels are in common between the frames. Are you able to provide sample rows that actually produce some results?

Comment: Try sqldf("select ...", dbname = tempfile())` to cause it to perform the joins outside of R.  You will still need enough memory to hold the result though.

Comment: @r2evans  yes my final goal  is to add rat and mouse ensemble transcript to its respective human ortholog with my result table which i was able to do for c.elegan because that was small , i have given the `dput`

Answer (score 0):

For a dataset of this size, you won't be able to simply join your data in a naive way and keep working on it interactively. The best approach will depend on what you expect to to with it.

Maybe you'll need to work in a sample. Maybe split data in chunks of manageable size. Maybe loading them into an Spark instance. Or maybe perform the calculations you need using SQL.

If all you want is the data joined, you can just load them into your database, perform the join and then export to CSV or another format. No need to load them into a data frame.

State your intent and others can help you better.

Comment: "Maybe split data in chunks of manageable size." shall i do the same in R? like split it in chunks and do it, i have updated my final goals and sample `dput()`